# Can't find table dbstat

Tags: python, windows, sqlite

```
c.execute('select sum(unused), sum(pgsize), sum(payload), count(*) from dbstat')
```

or

```
c.execute('select sum(unused), sum(pgsize), sum(payload), count(*) from main.dbstat')
```

I'm using `sqlite3` database, and I'm trying to get the statistics of the database from the `dbstat` table. This line works fine on `Linux` not on `Window`. In both cases I made sure that I'm using the same `sqlite3` version and the same `python3` version. I would love to know why this doesn't work on windows.

Error:

```
c.execute('select sum(unused), sum(pgsize), sum(payload), count(*) from dbstat') sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: dbstat
```

Comment: Hard to say for sure with just this select statement, but I'd say the most likely scenario is that your database path is incorrect in Windows (i.e. it's either opening up a different database, or didn't find a database at all and silently opened a new database).

Comment: The sqlite instance you're using probably wasn't compiled with [SQLITE_ENABLE_DBSTAT_VTAB](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_dbstat_vtab) defined.

Comment: Like Shawn said, look there:https://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html#epovtab

Comment: how do you run `SQLITE_ENABLE_DBSTAT_VTAB` ?

Comment: AAAhhhh, ok now I understand what you meant @Shawn . Does that mean that the executable for `Windows` has a different options enabled than the `Linux` executable?

Comment: Has nothing to do with executables. The options that were used when compiling whatever sqlite3 shared library the python sqlite bindings use is what matters.

Comment: @Shawn ... are you saying I should check what python sqlite3.dll ..... that doesn't make sense...aren't all the downloads for python have the same sqlite3.dll? <<not sure at this point ....

Answer (score 0):

@Shawn ... ok, figured out what was going on. Python on `Windows` has a different `sqlite3.dll` than Python on `Linux`. The one on `Windows` didn't have the `SQLITE_ENABLE_DBSTAT_VTAB`. To make it work, you can compile the sqlite3.dll yourself from the source code like @Shawn said or you can download the compiled dll from their website, where it has the option enabled, and add it do the `DLLs` folder in the python director.

You can check the sqlite3 compiled options by calling

```
PRAGMA compile_options;
```

If you want to check the python `sqlite3.dll` run this python script

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('PRAGMA compile_options;')
available_pragmas = c.fetchall()
print(available_pragmas)
conn.close()
```

Python3.7 output will look like this

```
[('COMPILER=msvc-1916',), ('ENABLE_FTS4',), ('ENABLE_FTS5',), ('THREADSAFE=1',)]
```